# How to aggregate on several string columns in a pyspark dataframe groupby object?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate

I have a pyspark dataframe with many columns of *string* and *double* types on the following form:

```py
+---+---+--------+-----+------+----+
|tin|ecu|DcyStart|did1 |did2  |did3|
+---+---+--------+-----+------+----+
|1  |1  |1       |34   |null  |null|
|1  |1  |2       |null |2     |null|
|1  |1  |3       |null |null  |b   |
|1  |1  |4       |null |null  |null|
|1  |2  |1       |40   |null  |null|
|1  |2  |2       |null |2     |null|
|1  |2  |3       |null |null  |f   |
|1  |2  |4       |null |null  |null|
+---+---+--------+----+-------+----+
```

Where each of the *did*-columns should only have values in rows with a certain value of *DcyStart*. I am not interested in the information in DcyStart, and i would like to remove it to reduce the table size and get rid of null entries.

I tried grouping on *tin* and *ecu* and then aggregating all *did*-columns over the range of *DcyStart* with different functions like `first()`, `max()` and so on, but these functions fail because of one of two reasons:

- agg function can not handle *strings*
- agg function can only take one column as argument

I have tried several variations of the code below:

```py
list_of_dids = ["did1", "did2", "did3"]
data.groupBy("tin", "ecu").first(*list_of_dids)
```

but it always gives me one of the two errors listed above.

There are 100+ different *did*-columns, and some of then could possibly have values for more than one *DcyStart*, but if that is the case any of them would do for the "aggregation".

What i would like to achieve is this:

```py
+---+----+-----+----+----+
|tin|ecu||did1 |did2|did3|
+---+----+-----+----+----+
|1  |1   |34   |2   |b   |
|1  |2   |40   |2   |f   |
+---+----+-----+----+----+
```

How the hell do i solve this? o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_dids = ["did1", "did2", "did3"]
from pyspark.sql.functions import first, max
list(map(lambda x: max(x), list_of_dids))
df.groupBy("tin", "ecu").agg(*list(map(lambda x: max(x), list_of_dids))).show()
```

try this. groupBy().agg() and you can do multiple aggregations in one run.